# Need help in being able to write the Questions in a more mathematical manner

Tags: support

Can someone please tell me how do I write comments involving mathematical techniques as it appears in text books. Say for eg. I wish to write summation of q_i over all integral values of i as it would have appeared in a math text book having a sigma notation and everything...

Comment: You can see a lot of examples by clicking on “edit” to see the source of existing posts. Press Escape or Back or close the browser tab to abandon the edit.